# Why Could not find artifacts for contract from any sources

Tags: truffle, ethereumjs, truffle-migration, truffle-contract

I am using windows 10 with truffle and ganache-cli. I have 2 contracts file to be deployed contain interfaces of other contracts defined within the contract:

Contracts:

**ERC721Mintable.sol**

- Ownable
- Pausable is Ownable
- ERC165
- ERC721 is Pausable, ERC165
- ERC721Enumerable is ERC165, ERC721
- ERC721MetaData is ERC721Enumerable, usingOraclize
- CraveuERC721Token is ERC721MetaData

**Verifier.sol**

**SolnSquareVerifier.sol**

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.21 <0.6.0;

import "./ERC721Mintable.sol";
import "./Verifier.sol";

contract SolnSqaureVerifier is CraveuERC721Token {

    SquareVerifier squareVerifier;

    constructor(address verifierAddress) public {
        squareVerifier = SquareVerifier(verifierAddress);
    }
```

Here's my deploy_contracts.js:

```
const SquareVerifier = artifacts.require("Verifier");
const SolnSquareVerifier = artifacts.require("SolnSquareVerifier");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(SquareVerifier).then( () => {
    return deployer.deploy(SolnSquareVerifier, SquareVerifier.address);
  });
};
```

I am using truffle version 5.0.18

> Error Produced: Error: Error: Could not find artifacts for
>   SolnSquareVerifier from any sources

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of an artifact is defined according to the contract's name, not the file's name.

Typically, the best practice is to have both names identical.

In your case, however, it seems that:

- `SolnSquareVerifier` is the file's name
- `SolnSqaureVerifier` is the contract's name

Note that the `a` and `u` appear in a different order in each name.

Comment: Ahh couldn't find out that typo! My Bad :/ Thanks a lot thought